# How to use session user in flutter?

Tags: http, dart, flutter

I've been trying to make user login and register with http in flutter using dart. Somehow i want to make user stay at the app using session or cookie. Anyone have been trying it yet?

Comment: What part causes you troubles? You need to handle cookies yourself. You can read them from HTTP responses and send them with requests. You can store them on the device using for example https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks somehow i managed it successfuly using shared pref :)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [requests](https://github.com/jossef/requests)

- as of now, it uses [shared_preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) which is not the best practice (security-wise) to store sensitive data (session-ids etc) [Issue #1](https://github.com/jossef/requests/issues/1)

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  requests: ^1.0.0
```

Usage:

```
import 'package:requests/requests.dart';

// ...

// this will persist cookies
await Requests.post("https://example.com/api/v1/login", body: {"username":"...", "password":"..."} ); 

// this will re-use the persisted cookies
dynamic data = await Requests.get("https://example.com/api/v1/stuff", json: true);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a user session instead of HTTP session, check out [flutter_session](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_session).

It's really easy to implement and persists through pages even after navigating.